# How to open Website as App in Microsoft Edge from CLI?

Tags: google-chrome, command-line, progressive-web-apps, microsoft-edge

In Chrome you can use

```
start chrome --new-window --app=http://www.example.com
```

To have it open in a reduced window (PWA-Style).
[Chrome as app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5rKi.png)

How is this possible with MicrosoftEdge?

Comment: Try ```start msedge www.example.com```

Comment: This starts edge normally, not in app mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using the **MS Edge (Chromium)** browser.

You just need to replace the `Chrome` with the `msedge` in your above-posted command.

Modified command:

`start msedge --new-window --app=http://Your_Website_URL_here`

**Output with the Microsoft Edge:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works. I just wonder why it is different to `start MicrosoftEdge --new-window --app=http://www.example.com`

Comment: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '--app=http://localhost'

Comment: I remove `--new-window` and it works.